# How to cast a variable of type MLlib vector type to ML vector type?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, machine-learning, k-means

It is a question about Spark and Scala
I want to make a user-item rating matrix and put each row of this matrix into ml KMeans algorithm.
So I wrote as follows:

```
 val rawData = sc.textFile("/user/ubuntu/SunLu/ml-100k/u.data").map(_.split("\t").take(3))
   import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.distributed.{MatrixEntry, CoordinateMatrix}
   val data = rawData.map{ case Array(i, j, value) => MatrixEntry(i.toLong, j.toLong, value.toDouble)}
   val df = new CoordinateMatrix(data).toIndexedRowMatrix().row.toDF("user", "features")
```

At the end, I got a dataframe like follows:
[df.show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEjYH.png)

And then I got userVectors with this code:`val userVectors = df.select("features")`
And I applied it into ml Kmeans algortihm but I got an error as follows:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCVdN.png)
I do not konw how to transform a `mllib vector` to a `ml vector`.
And how to apply `ml KMeans` algorithm with `userVectors` which I have got.